# Videosink on Gstreamer 1.2.3 (iOS)

Tags: ios, video, gstreamer

Does gstreamer for ios currently support displaying video. I'm following the tutorial which calls for creating a pipeline

```
gst_parse_launch("videotestsrc ! warptv ! videoconvert ! autovideosink", &error);"
```

and then connecting the video overlay.

```
video_sink = gst_bin_get_by_interface(GST_BIN(pipeline), GST_TYPE_VIDEO_OVERLAY);
```

Howerver, `video_sink` is always `nil`. If I change the pipeline to just `playbin` that works, but `playbin` is for playing from a URI, but I need to construct a full gstreamer video pipeline.

I also can't find any video sinks other than `autovideosink`. Is displaying a gstreamer video pipeline currently supported for ios?

This is on ios 7.1 with gstreamer 1.2.3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With some help from the mailing list I have got test video displaying. I put up my working version of the [ios video tutorial app](https://github.com/braincorp/gstreamer_ios_tutorial).

The short answer is that gstreamer 1.2.3 does have support for video displaying using `eglglessink`. However, you need to modify the `#defines` in `gst_ios_init.h` to make sure `eglglessink` is included. You also need to use a `GLKView` to provide GL primitives and the `video_overlay` methods to set this up.

I found it difficult to discover this from the documentation so hopefully some others may find the tutorial useful.